# spring-boot-logger.log file location for deployed spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9, spring-logback

I followed [this](http://spring-boot-logger.log%20location) tutorial to setup spring boot logging in my app and it work correctly in my development environment but not after I deploy the app.

The spring app log files should go to `${CATALINA_BASE}/logs/spring-boot-logger.log` when app is deployed. How do I configure that?

My logback-spring.xml:

```
<property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

<appender name="Console"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFile"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
    <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/spring-boot-logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>

<!-- LOG "com.baeldung*" at TRACE level -->
<logger name="xxx.app" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</logger>
```

When I start the app on the deployment server using this configuration I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollingFile] - Failed to create parent directories for [/./logs/spring-boot-logger.log]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollingFile] - openFile(./logs/spring-boot-logger.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/spring-
boot-logger.log (No such file or directory)
```

I also tried configuring `logging.file.name = ${catalina.base}/logs/${service.name}.log` in application.properties like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122270/spring-boot-external-war-run-in-apache-tomcat-has-no-log) but then I receive an error when running `mvn clean install` locally

```
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'catalina.base' in value "${catalina.base}/logs/${service.name}.log"
```

Comment: How are you deploying your application? It seems you want to deploy it in an external Tomcat, but the lack of the `catalina.base` property indicates that you are running it using the embedded Tomcat.

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz I am deploying it to an external Tomcat. Locally I use the embedded Tomcat. I change my pom.xml accordingly (commenting/uncommenting 
`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to write your log file to the `${CATALINA_BASE}/logs` directory, but you used `./logs` in your configuration file. This would of course work if the working directory of your Tomcat server were `${CATALINA_BASE}`, but it is unsafe to assume anything about the *working directory* of the Tomcat server (and in your case it's not `${CATALINA_BASE}`).

Use [variable substitution](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) in your `logback-spring.xml` file:

```xml
<property name="LOGS" value="${catalina.base:-.}/logs" />
```

The default value `.` will be used when there is no `catalina.base` property (i.e. when you use the embedded Tomcat).

Comment: This is working fine.  Thank you !